# Multiple conditional statement with group_by in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a field that I need to run multiple conidtional statements (if/else) based on a group_by function with SERIAL being the group by. I want to create a new field that is added to df with the mutate() function.

Summary of data:

```
SERIAL INSTALLSITE_CONTRACT_PARTY_NUM INSTALLSITEDUNS_CONTRACT_POD INSTALLSITEPOD_CONTRACT_POD percent_dist
1: ZKZYKBAI                          MATCH                     MISMATCH                       MATCH            0
2: ZLLEJUWA                          MATCH                     MISMATCH                       MATCH            0
3: ZICZVXYG                          MATCH                        MATCH                       MATCH            0
4: ZXQPVFHB                          MATCH                        MATCH                       MATCH            0
5: ZLIUJARF                          MATCH                        MATCH                       MATCH            0
6: ZCUXHMIE                          MATCH                        MATCH                       MATCH            0
```

I need to write if the matches are equal or not - IF 'INSTALLSITE_CONTRACT_PARTY_NUM' = 'MATCH' & 'INSTALLSITEDUNS_CONTRACT_POD' = 'MATCH' & INSTALLSITEPOD_CONTRACT_POD = 'MATCH' & percent_dist <= 0 THEN 'ACCURATE'...

There are multiple conditions that looks like above but I wanted to get an idea of how I can use this approach in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the format of the input data, it seems like a `data.table`.  So, we could use the efficient data.table methods.  Specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`.  Loop over the columns with `lapply`, create a `list` of logical vectors and `Reduce` it to a single logical `vector`, then add more conditions i.e. with 'percent_dist' and use that in `i` to change the column 'ACCURATE' to a specified value

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- c('INSTALLSITE_CONTRACT_PARTY_NUM', 
        'INSTALLSITEDUNS_CONTRACT_POD',
         'INSTALLSITEPOD_CONTRACT_POD')
i1 <- dt1[, percent_dist <= 0 & Reduce(`&`, 
             lapply(.SD, `==`, 'MATCH')), .SDcols = nm1]
dt1[i1, ACCURATE := val]
```

Comment: This is excellent - Thank you! How would I add an additional statment (Say two fields match and another mismatch and percent is greater than 0)? Do I need to make multiple variables like i1? Thank you again for the quick response @akrun

Comment: @Dinho if it is different comparison, then you may have to write different statement as I thought the same condition is applied to all the columns with INSTALLSITE

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is multiple conditions (all possible comparisons on the match fields) and factoring in percent_dist between 0-1. @akrun

Comment: @Dinho You could use `Map` as well with comparison operators as a `list`

Answer (score 1):

You can use dplyr's `case_when` to handle multiple conditions like so:

```r
dt <- grouped_data %>%
    mutate(
      new_col = case_when(
        INSTALLSITE_CONTRACT_PARTY_NUM == 'MATCH' &
        INSTALLSITEDUNS_CONTRACT_POD == 'MATCH' &
        INSTALLSITEPOD_CONTRACT_POD == 'MATCH' &
        percent_dist <= 0 ~ 'Accurate',
        ...
        other_condition ~ 'result',
        ...
        T ~ 'default result'
      )
    )
```